# Split lines from text to key and value and search for a value based on the key

Tags: python-3.x

I have text file with the following data:

```
typename : APP, DTRAFFIC, DSCHANGE, SEARCH
socio_citysize : up to 1.999 inhabitants, 2.000 inh to 2.999 inh, 3.000 inh to 4.999 inh
socio_hhincome : up to 499 EUR, 500 EUR - 749 EUR, 750 EUR - 999 EUR, 1000 EUR - 1249 EUR
socio_education : college degree, higher school education w/o job training
socio_occupation : employee, freelancer, housewife
```

I want to split the data into key and value. Key - typename,socio_citysize,... and the values corresponding to this keys.
This is my code, but there is issue with it, because it always returns the last line no matter what key I use in the print.

```
def read_lists(file_name, key):
list_key = []
list_value = []
data_dict = {}
with open(file_name, mode='r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        key, value = line.split(' : ')
        list_key.append(key)
        list_value.append(value)
        data_dict = dict(zip(list_key,list_value))
    return data_dict[key]
print(read_lists('data_list.txt', 'socio_hhincome'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable `key` to `inkey` in your function but not in for loop.

```
def read_lists(file_name, inkey): # Here
    list_key = []
    list_value = []
    data_dict = {}
    with open(file_name, mode='r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
        for line in data:
            key, value = line.split(' : ')
            list_key.append(key)
            list_value.append(value)
            data_dict = dict(zip(list_key,list_value))

        return data_dict[inkey] # Here

print(read_lists('data_list.txt', 'socio_hhincome'))
```

It is duplicated. My result is correct.

```
up to 499 EUR, 500 EUR - 749 EUR, 750 EUR - 999 EUR, 1000 EUR - 1249 EUR
```